# Could not find any matches for com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.+

Tags: flutter, facebook-audience-network

Hello  flutter developer i am using  facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.1 plugin in my app for integrate facebook audience network ads .it was working fine even my app is live on playstore.Ads still showing int it today's. I want update my app adding some new feature when i debug my app for testing the ads i got this error below anyone tell me what is issue i thought it was plugin outdated now ?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on RMX2020 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.+ as no versions of com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/6.13.6/audience-network-sdk-6.13.6.pom
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/audience-network-sdk/6.13.6/audience-network-sdk-6.13.6.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :facebook_audience_network

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ac2S.png)

This is the temporary solution.because i am not able to update this packge so.
please check steps in image and add selected code in your facebook_audience_network packge.it's working in my all projects.

- please add sdk version same as your app/gradle file it's 99% working. only issue with sdk version specification.
- **and also comment old sdk.**

Comment: @yukit Gujarati what is temp lib?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

In `pubspec.yaml` depend on `https://github.com/azmasamy/facebook_audience_network.git` instead of `facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.1`

like this:

```
  # facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.1
  facebook_audience_network:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/azmasamy/facebook_audience_network.git
      ref: master
```

## Explanation

The problem is that the `facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.1` depends on `implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.+'` in `build.gradle`

It searches for the most recent version on `Maven Central` and for some reason it searches for 6.13.0 which doesn't exist.

I forked the latest version of `facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.1` and modified the dependency so that it depends on the most recent version which is 6.12.0.